# How to use paypal-ipn module?

Tags: meteor, paypal-ipn

Whenever i click submit on the form that should send a notification to my listener, i get a message that says `Cannot find module 'paypal-ipn'`.

When i track the error, it takes me to a line of code ib the IPN listener `var ipn = Meteor.npmRequire('paypal-ipn');`

I added papal-ipn in my package.json here

```
{
  "name": "application-name",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "paypal-ipn" : "3.0.0",
  "redis": "0.8.2",
  "github": "0.1.8",
  "body-parser": "1.14.1",
  "description": "Application description.",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "meteor --settings settings-development.json",
    "staging": "modulus env set METEOR_SETTINGS \"$(cat settings-development.json)\" -p 'Staging' && modulus deploy -f -p 'Staging'",
    "production": "modulus env set METEOR_SETTINGS \"$(cat settings-production.json)\" -p 'Production' && modulus deploy -f -p 'Production'"
  }
}
```

What is the mistake am doing? help PLEASE

Comment: did you run npm install ?

Comment: @ozOli no, when i tried now, i got this error : "npm WARN EPACKAGEJSON application-name@1.0.0 No repository field.
npm WARN EPACKAGEJSON application-name@1.0.0 No license field."

Comment: ok try removing what you added to the package.json Run npm install --save  paypal-ipn  and that will add the required info to the package.json automatically for you.

Comment: @ozOli yes it worked, THANKS A LOT!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok try removing what you added to the package.json Run npm install --save paypal-ipn and that will add the required info to the package.json automatically for you.